# remove alias and merge github commit (update files w/ commit in github repo)

Tags: git, github, git-commit

I have used other source control applications like Versions, and Cornerstone; but I am new to github. I have just made a first commit, and all the updated files I had moved into my working directory to commit, have added to my directory / repo with filename extension '`alias`' added to the end of each file and did not replace or merge with previous files.

My work flow is working locally and once files are strong and tested, I would commit into git repo / directory to replace older files with update. Currently I added the files to the directory to commit and files add as duplicate almost and with file extension '`alias`'.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that making a commit will never replace your old commit, both commits are saved as separate versions.

If you have added the files once, you need not do that every time before you commit unless you have removed them.